# Calculating motor power and motor needs for 200 lbs load

Tags: arduino, motor

I'm trying to make a load carrying robot which will follow a line and will have capacity to carry 200 lbs on concrete surface. What should be the horsepower for electrical motor to handle this on 0 degree incline and 4 degree incline? Can I control it with Arduino or similar boards?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a link](http://www2.mae.ufl.edu/designlab/motors/EML2322L%20Drive%20Wheel%20Motor%20Torque%20Calculations.pdf)
 to Drive Wheel Motor Torque Calculations which is used to decide torque required by mobile robot.

Hope this helps.....